# Pattern-matching algorithm for lists

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I am trying some pattern matching in Python. I have two lists as follows:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3]
b = [3,4,5,2,1,7,8,9,1]
```

Now I want to retrieve some common patterns

```
c = [3,4,5,7,8,9,1]
```

Is there a library that can help me with this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: You could start by coming up with a "definition"of what you mean by pattern that is more than a single example with no explanation.

Comment: Are you effectively looking for the intersection of two sets -- ie `set(a) ^ set(b)` ?

Comment: @F1Rumors That looks good but what if a and b have duplicates?

Comment: @Ekoji - can you update your example to show how you wish duplicates to be handled?

Comment: @F1Rumors How about now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hacked something together for you. This returns the longest list c that is an ordered sublist of both a and b. In other words, the longest list that can be obtained by deleting elements from either a or b without changing their order.

```
def match(a, b):
  if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
    return []

  if a[0] == b[0]:
    return [a[0]] + match(a[1:], b[1:])

  return max(match(a, b[1:]), match(a[1:], b), key=len)
```

Here's the output:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3]
>>> b = [3,4,5,2,1,7,8,9,1]
>>> match(a, b)
[3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1]
```

In the future, it's always a good idea to write a definition of what it is you want to achieve. That way, other people can better understand you, and functions can be checked against the definition to see if they are correct. You will get a better idea how to do this if you study more mathematics. Combinatorics and number theory are two subfields closely related to computer science and programming. Good luck!

Comment: The last four lines could be replaced by `return max(match(a, b[1:]), match(a[1:], b), key=len)`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, that's much more elegant, thanks.